# One time fire trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

When I first started coding in GAS I was using time based triggers and then deleting them when I started the next iteration (to get around time limits). I have since seen someone use a trigger that fires just once so I don't have to worry about deleting it, but I can't seem to find that example.

Old way:

```
//- This function deletes the running triggers from the repository creation process. it does NOT delete the form or 
//- timed run triggers
function deleteTrigger() {

    Logger.log("Deleting Triggers?");

    // Loop over all triggers and delete them
    var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {

        var id = allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction();
        Logger.log(id);

        if (id == "callCopy"){ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]); Logger.log("I deleted the copy files trigger");}

    }
}

//This is the trigger to restart the call copy script in the right place. 
function createTrigger() {

    // Trigger every 1 minute
    Logger.log("Creating File Copy Trigger");
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('callCopy')
        .timeBased()
        .everyMinutes(1)
        .create();
}
```

Comment: You mean `Trigger.after(ms)`? Check documentation of trigger builder class

Comment: ah there it is! thanks.